# Browser doesn't show progress bar when downloading a file in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, .net-core, browser

When i click download , I am not able to see download progress in browser but i can see file download progress in network tab of debugger tool chrome
This is the client side Angular code to dowload the  Zip file

```
  onDownloadClick(ID: number) {
    this.ehiExportService.downloadRequestFiles(ID).subscribe((response) => {
      const stringArray = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition')?.split(';');
      let fileName = 'PatientExportRequest.zip';

      if (stringArray !== undefined) {
        for (const word of stringArray) {
          if (word.toLowerCase().includes('filename')) {
            fileName = word.split('=')[1];
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      const blob: Blob = response.body as Blob;
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      if (fileName !== null && fileName !== undefined) {
        a.download = fileName;
      } else {
        a.download = fileName;
      }
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.click();
    });
  }

  downloadRequestFiles(requestID: number) {
   
      uri = this.buildRestCoreUri(
        `api/ehiexport/DownloadFile`,
        `?requestID=${requestID}&userId=${this.hostComm.getUser().id}&organizationId=${
          this.hostComm.getUser().organizationId
        }`
      );

    const headers = this.getAuthHeaders();

    return this.http.get(uri, { headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'json', observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        console.error('Error occurred during download:', error);
        return [];
      })
    );
  }
```

This is server side code to fetch the file and give it to the client
The given C# method is an HTTP GET endpoint that retrieves and serves a ZIP file for download with appropriate response headers and error handling.

```
        [HttpGet("DownloadFile")]
        public IActionResult DownloadZip(int requestId, decimal userId, decimal organizationId)
        {
            try
            {
                              
                DownloadRequest eHIDownloadRequest;

                eHIDownloadRequest = ehiExportRepository.GetDownloadRequest(requestId, userId, organizationId);

                if (eHIDownloadRequest != null)
                {
                    string zipFilePath = eHIDownloadRequest.FileName;

                    Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentLength, new FileInfo(zipFilePath).Length.ToString());
                    Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentType, "application/zip");
                    Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, "attachment; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipFilePath) + "_" + requestId + ".zip\"");

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(zipFilePath))
                    {
                        Trace($"Started reading the file {zipFilePath}");
                        FileStream streamFile = new FileStream(zipFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        Trace($"Read the file {zipFilePath}");
                        return File(streamFile, "application/zip", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipFilePath) + "_" + requestId + ".zip");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Error($"Error: {zipFilePath} not found");
                        throw new FileNotFoundException(zipFilePath);
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Error("Error: Request not returned, please check whether the request is completed.");
                    throw new Exception("Error: Request not returned, please check whether the request is completed.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Error("EHI Download Zip failed", e);
                return ServerError($"Problem occurred while downloading the file, please contact administrator.");
            }
        }
```